# How do I combine feature-state and property based fill-color in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to combine a hover effect and property based fill as a fallback. Thus if it is hovered, use property based fill, if not use black. I tried the code below, but got the error "Expected color but found object instead.". How do I combine feature-state with property based fill?

```
                "fill-color": [
                    "case",
                    ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
                    "#000",
                    ['literal', {
                        property: "variable",
                        stops: [
                            [0.7, "#FFFF00"],
                            [0.8, "#FFBA07"],
                            [0.9, "#FFA30A"],
                            [0.95, "#FF1A1A"]
                        ]
                    }]
                ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly trying to combine old and new syntax. Instead of:

```
['literal', {
  property: "variable",
  stops: [
    [0.7, "#FFFF00"],
    [0.8, "#FFBA07"],
    [0.9, "#FFA30A"], 
    [0.95, "#FF1A1A"] 
  ]
}]
```

you want something like:

```
['match', ['get', 'variable'], 
    0.7, "#FFFF00",
    0.8, "#FFBA07",
    0.9, "#FFA30A", 
    0.95, "#FF1A1A" 

]
```